# Mercurial Version Control show error in push

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

I am using Mercurial version control for my project. Everything like `push`,`pull`,`update` is doing okay but one thing is going wrong: when I am using `push` it is showing something like this

```
warning: bitbucket.org certificate with fingerprint 24:9c:45:8b:9c:aa:ba:55:4e:01:6d:58:ff:e4:28:7d:2a:14:ae:3b not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
```

Can someone tell me where is the wrong part. Any help and suggestions are highly appreciable.

Comment: Do you check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting?

Comment: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CACertificates#Windows

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally I got the solution by checking the following pages: [CACertificates](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CACertificates) and 
http://tadabborat-blog.tumblr.com/post/9502320721/mercurial-warning-bitbucketorg-certificate-with.

Comment: Newer links: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CACertificates http://tadabborat-blog.tumblr.com/post/9502320721/mercurial-warning-bitbucketorg-certificate-with

Answer (score 35):

Putting this in my .hgrc did the trick.

```
[hostfingerprints]
bitbucket.org = 45:ad:ae:1a:cf:0e:73:47:06:07:e0:88:f5:cc:10:e5:fa:1c:f7:99
```

You should check the fingerprint first by viewing the host's certificate. But if all looks fine you could use the above approach to do away with those pesky warnings.

See https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BBKB/abort%3A+certificate+for+bitbucket.org+has+unexpected+fingerprint

Answer (score -1):

Got this message from 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BBKB/abort%3A+certificate+for+bitbucket.org+has+unexpected+fingerprint

Bitbucket's certificates have changed to use SHA-2 since 6 May 2015. You'll need to update your local Mercurial configuration as follows:

Find your global Mercurial configuration file ....
For Windows, this file is called Mercurial.ini and is usually found in your user profile's home directory. For example (C:\Users\whoever\Mercurial.ini)
For Unix/OSX, this file is called .hgrc and is found in ~/.hgrc (your home directory)

Edit the line below [hostfingerprints] to reflect the new certificate

```
[hostfingerprints]
bitbucket.org = 46:de:34:e7:9b:18:cd:7f:ae:fd:8b:e3:bc:f4:1a:5e:38:d7:ac:24
```

Updated the windows Mercurial.ini file, after that no problem.  Using Mercurial  with Sourcetree.