# Pull Changes from repository warning: bitbucket.org certificate with fingerprint ssh

Tags: eclipse, bitbucket

- configure `Bitbucket` with `Eclipse` using following [Steps](http://smalltowngeeks.net/2011/02/13/subversion-set-up-configuring-bit-bucket-with-eclipse/)
- When going to pull the project using there Url, UserName, password on `Bitbucket` then getting Error like.

> warning: bitbucket.org certificate with fingerprint
>   24:9c:45:8b:9c:aa:ba:55:4e:01:6d:58:ff:e4:28:7d:2a:14:ae:3b not
>   verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
>       abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
>       warning: bitbucket.org certificate with fingerprint 24:9c:45:8b:9c:aa:ba:55:4e:01:6d:58:ff:e4:28:7d:2a:14:ae:3b not
>   verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
>       abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

[image]

i have also check [Link1](http://tadabborat.tumblr.com/post/9502320721/mercurial-warning-bitbucket-org-certificate-with)

but don't know where to update this below details

Either edit the `~/.hgrc` or the `<MERCURIAL_REPO_DIR>/.hg/hgrc` and add the following section to it:

Also same related [question like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854399/mercurial-version-control-show-error-in-push)

Answer (score 0):

on windows the path would be "%HOMEPATH%\mercurial.ini"

but /.hg/hgrc is the same on windows